# Adjacency List add relations

Tags: java, graph, nullpointerexception, adjacency-list

I just started working with graphs and I am trying to build a adjacency list using cities.  The two cities are sent into the addRelation method.  I am trying say that if there already isn't a vertex that matches the first or last string, create a new vertex with the string that doesn't already exist.  Right now all I get is a null pointer exception at the line with the ***.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong or what I should be doing?

```
public class AdjList {

public class Node{
    int num;
    Node next;
    Node(int num, Node next){
        this.num=num;
        this.next=next;
    }
}

public class Vertex{
    String city;
    Node list;
    Vertex(String city, Node next){
        this.city=city;
        this.list=next;
    }
}

Vertex [] aList= new Vertex [50];

void addRelation(String from, String to) {
    for(int i=0; i<aList.length; i++){
        ****if(!aList[i].city.equals(from)){****
            aList[i]=new Vertex(from, null);
        }       
        if(aList[i].city.equals(from)){
            aList[i]=new Vertex(from, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    AdjList g = new AdjList ();
    g.addRelation("Atlanta",  "Chattanooga");
    g.addRelation("Chattanooga",  "Nashville");
    g.addRelation("Chattanooga",  "Knoxville");
    g.addRelation("Atlanta",  "Birmingham");
    g.addRelation("Greenville", "Knoxville");
}
```

Comment: the `aList` array is full of nulls right now. So when you access `aList[i]` it will throw a NPE

Comment: @AlejandroLucena so I have to first check if aList[i]==null?

Comment: Well, yes and no. You can do that approach, or before calling `addRelation` you loop through and fill the array with dummy `Vertex` instances.

Comment: On another note, why do you have 3 `public` classes within each other?

Comment: @AlejandroLucena can you not do that?

Comment: Well you can, but I don't think it is necessarily the cleanest coding style, but then again I haven't been Java coding for a little while

Answer (score 0):

In the line of code where you wrote

```
Vertex [] aList= new Vertex [50];
```

That is only allocating you enough space for you to *potentially* hold up to 50 `Vertex` items. This does not mean however, that the array will be filled with them right after allocation. So you basically have the *capacity* to store 50 `Vertex` items.

In your method `addRelation` it is checking if `!aList[i].city.equals(from)`, however the `aList` array does not have any actual `Vertex` objects, so when you try to query the `city` field from `aList[i]`, you are essentially trying to query a null object, hence the null pointer exception.

There are two workarounds for this.

- Check for null before continuing in the loop ( as you suggested in the comments)
- Fill the array with dummy `Vertex` objects before calling any methods.

The dummy approach would require you to initialize the objects with either empty strings/null arguments for constructor arguments, or you can implement the default constructor and just say `new Vertex()` and then customize the `city` and `next` fields of the `Vertex` object in your code logic.

Comment: Is one of those options better than the other?

Comment: I guess that would be implementation specific, and is a coding style preference. If memory were a big issue, then only adding when you need to would obviously be the optimal option(checking if null within the loop).

Comment: okay.  So besides the checking if it is null.  Am I adding to an adjacency matrix correctly?

Comment: Well, that depends. I haven't seen the rest of your code, or its logic. And just to clarify, you just said adjacency matrix but in the title you said adjacency list. I'm assuming you want list?